# Chrome Gives me a Permission Error on a URL That's in my Manifest's "permissions"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've got a Chrome extension, and when I try to run:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { code });
```

I get the following error:

> _generated_background_page.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1-GbuMXy-CoQAi005-YCJ7Lq_73oVi-1qc-AUnsS6YjI/edit#slide=id.g36de8e2a97_0_0". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

... but I have docs.google.com in my extension's "permissions" list in `manifest.json`:

"permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "storage",
      "tabs",
      "http://*/",
      "https://*/",
      "https://docs.google.com/*",
      "http://*.google.com/*",
      "https://*.google.com/*",
      "https://*.gstatic.com/*"
    ]

As you can see I also have permissions for "tabs", so I can't figure out why I keep getting this error.  Any ideas?

P.S. When I check (from within my `background.js` dev tools console):

```
chrome.permissions.getAll(all => console.log(all))
```

it even lists Google.com:

```
{
  origins:["http://*.google.com/*", "http://*/*", "https://*.google.com/*", "https://*.gstatic.com/*", "https://*/*", "https://docs.google.com/*"],
  permissions: ["activeTab", "storage", "tabs"]
}
```

Comment: Assuming you can reproduce it in a new browser profile, it definitely looks like a bug. You can report it on https://crbug.com. Try adding `"activeTab"` to permissions.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding `activeTab` but it didn't help :(

Comment: Gah, it was the profile! !#@^!&($)&!#@*$(&*_@! Chrome!  I don't know how they expect people to develop in an environment that constantly gets bugged for no reason and can't be fixed without restarting the browser.  Thanks for the suggestion though.